# Google Play on Android 4.0 emulator

Tags: android, google-play

How can I install the Google Play .apk onto my Android 4.0 emulator?

Comment: Note:  comments have mixed results, so your mileage may vary

Comment: but its the same with other emulator versions, and it worked there so why it shoudnt work in 4.x? :)

Answer (score 259):

Download Google apps (GoogleLoginService.apk , GoogleServicesFramework.apk  , Phonesky.apk)
 from [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120629212513/http://wiki.rootzwiki.com/Google_Apps#Universal_Packages_2).

Start your emulator:

```
emulator -avd VM_NAME_HERE -partition-size 500 -no-audio -no-boot-anim
```

Then use the following commands:

```
# Remount in rw mode.
# NOTE: more recent system.img files are ext4, not yaffs2
adb shell mount -o remount,rw -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock0 /system

# Allow writing to app directory on system partition
adb shell chmod 777 /system/app

# Install following apk
adb push GoogleLoginService.apk /system/app/.
adb push GoogleServicesFramework.apk /system/app/.
adb push Phonesky.apk /system/app/. # Vending.apk in older versions
adb shell rm /system/app/SdkSetup*
```

Comment: Note: Vending.apk is called Phonesky.apk in latest releases

Comment: Server Offline. Please hang tight while we get this resolved. :'(

Comment: When installing with this method, I can register and login, but get an error `Error retrieving information from server [RH-01]` afterwards.

Comment: the ***-partition-size*** param is important, without it i got OutOfMemory exception while pushing the apks

Comment: When installing with this method it worked by me only with the default data network, however it had a error logging in when I was on a different APN, so make sure you do not use any proxy for the Access Point

Comment: I think this answer should be the accepted answer. After all, this IS an actual answer, the current accepted answer (11/11/2013) is only a "breaking the eula is like a bad thing, m'kay?" type of comment.

Comment: Does anyone have problem with connecting to Google services after installing Play this way on emulator?

Comment: Should I follow this instructions in emulator image with Google Play API services?

Comment: If you also want to be able to use a 4.0.3 emulator for GCM testing, you will also need to add the GmsCore.apk from the 4.3 package [here](http://goo.im/gapps). Here is a [direct link](http://goo.im/gapps/gapps-jb-20130813-signed.zip)

Comment: Am I the only one not able to get this to work?  On both 4.4 and 5.0 emulators, adding the APKs does not show the Play Store icon, and `adb reboot` just hangs.

Comment: The link to download Google Play services are not working anymore. I think the root link http://goo.im/gapps itself is removed.

Comment: I'm unable to see play store icon on emulator after Successfully following all steps......is there any caveat to this method? Im running android 5.1 emulator image

Comment: all was working fine but after closing the emulator and starting it again with eclipse is removing the playstore
is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: Links Are:-  https://electrocoder.googlecode.com/files/GoogleLoginService.apk  , https://androidmarketu.googlecode.com/files/GoogleServicesFramework.apk , https://drive.google.com/a/sakshay.in/file/d/0B2ykO0YZXDgQMmNfbThJVzJHb2s

Comment: getting rm: /system/app/SdkSetup: is a directory error on api 22

Comment: adb push seems to have problem `failed to copy 'GoogleLoginService.apk' to 'C:/Program Files/Git/system/app/': No such file or directory` when using window gitbash. Solved by using window cmd

Comment: looks like this methos only works in android 4.x, in android 5 it fails for some kind of certifcated Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES]

Comment: I'm gettin `system not in proc/mounts`. Trying on a 7.1 emulator

Answer (score 85):

For future visitors.

As of now Android 4.2.2 platform includes Google Play services. Just use an emulator running Jelly Bean. Details can be found here:

[Setup Google Play Services SDK](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html)

**EDIT:**

Another option is to use [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/) (runs way faster)

**EDIT 2:**

As @gdw2 commented: *"setting up the Google Play Services SDK does not install a working Google Play app -- it just enables certain services provided by the SDK"*

After version 2.0 Genymotion does not come with Play Services by default, but it can be **easily** installed manually. Just download the right version from [here](http://www.android.gs/download-install-and-flash-google-apps-for-android) and drag and drop into the virtual device (emulador).

Comment: do you mean that Genymotion's vms have a google play implementation in them?

Comment: @craig65535 if you are using the map api, some people are having issues with that, that's way I recommended Genymotion.

Comment: Holy mother! Genymotion is suweet!

Comment: Genymotion is faster than the emulated ARM image.  It is probably the same speed as the HAXM-enabled x86 android image that is available with the Android SDK.

Comment: @Exception-al I think you should update your answer to clarify that setting up the Google Play Services SDK does not install a working Google Play app -- it just enables certain services provided by the SDK.

Comment: +1 for suggesting Genymotion!!! I didn't know it existed and now I can't live without it. It plays flawlessly with Android Studio (just add the plugin) and now I can debut my Google Maps V2 apps without resorting to "real" devices! Thanks a million!

Comment: Genymotion is so cool at perfomance, but still there is no Play app, so I don't have desired opportunity to install custom apps/

Comment: Thanks, I've already voted up. But can you please also share if there any tutorial of how to set up Eclipse to work with Genymotion.

Comment: @Johnny_D Genymotion works just like a real device. Just run it and it will be automatically detected by any IDE.

Comment: Some apps wont install via play store, says device is incompatible. I run a hardware benchmark and it blows the best phone out of the ball game. Not sure what its moaning baout. 4.3 -- But this is Genymotion is really awesome, looks like they did some serious work to the qemu emulator to enable 1GB ram and GPU pass through!

Comment: Installing Play store for Lollipop http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27045599/google-play-services-in-genymotion-on-lollipop-android-5-0

Comment: Just an observation: Genymotion uses VirtualBox. VirtualBox uses Intel-specific virtualiation optimizations. It may not be possible to emulate an ARM Android platform with GenyMotion. Perahps such a limitation may not be absolutely a show-stopper, not for all development channels. Genymotion may not be in all ways a 100% replacement for the QEmu-based AVD manager. Peraps, any projects using low-level ARM interfaces (kernel, LibC) may need to be tested on ARM hardware - viz a viz adb - if not to be tested initially in the AVD emulator, on a comp w/ a good fast microcontroller and lots of RAM.

Comment: @SeanChamp good point but final tests should always be on a real device

Comment: @Androiderson Totally. Concerning HW, I'm sure any well connected author could write a whole book chapter, even an Open Access book, as to how a Linux kernel fits into an Android platform - concerning any hardware-oriented distinctions that may be found in low-level Linux kernel interfaces for specific microcontrollers, also any specific kernel driver implementations for OEM specific hardware, So far as testing, OEM's may make their own testing channels, of course - as to how a whole Android OS may fit together in any single OEM service bundle, if not also for issue tracking in app production

Answer (score 27):

I do this in a more permanent way - instead of installing the APKs each time with `adb`, permanently add them to the system image that the emulator uses. You will need [Yaffey](http://code.google.com/p/yaffey/) on Windows, or a similar utility on other systems, to modify YAFFS2 images. Copy `GoogleLoginService.apk`, `GoogleServicesFramework.apk`, and `Phonesky.apk` (or `Vending.apk` in older versions of Android) to the `/system/app` folder of the `system.img` file of the emulator. Afterwards I can start the emulator normally, without messing with adb, and Play Store is always there.

## Obtaining the Google Play app from your device

Downloading Google Apps from some Internet site may not be quite legal, but if you have a phone or tablet with a corresponding Android version, just pull them out of your device:

```
adb -d root
adb -d pull /system/app/GoogleLoginService.apk
adb -d pull /system/app/GoogleServicesFramework.apk
adb -d pull /system/app/Phonesky.apk
```

You must have ***root-level access*** (run adb root) to the device in order to pull these files from it.

## Adding it to the image

Now start `yaffey` on Windows or a similar utility on Linux or Mac, and open `system.img` for the emulator image you want to modify. I modify most often the one in `[...]\android-sdk\system-images\android-17\x86`.

Rename the original `system.img` to `system-original.img`. Under yaffey, copy the APK files you pulled from your device to /app folder. Save your modified image as `system.img` in the original folder. Then start your emulator (in my case it would be Android 4.2 emulator with Intel Atom processor running under Intel HAX, super-fast on Windows machines) and you'll have Play Store there. I did not find it necessary to delete `SdkSetup.apk` and `SdkSetup.odex` - the Play Store and other services still work fine for me with these files present.

When finished with your testing, to alleviate your conscience guilty of temporarily pirating the Google Apps from your device, you may delete the modified `system.img` and restore the original from `system-original.img`.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a working YAFF2 editor for Linux—but fortunately, it turns out that with a one-line change, Yaffey itself compiles and runs on Linux. [Posted the steps I used on this Ask Ubuntu question.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/234258/how-to-mount-a-yaffs2-filesystem/281178#281178)

Comment: +1s are way too less for the aha- moment happiness..

StackOverflow should have a kiss-cos-ur-so-happy-button :)

Comment: I was able to pull the three APKs off of aa Android 4.1.2 phone without root, but I'm still working on getting them installed someplace else.

Comment: Any yaffey alternative for Mac?

Comment: @OlcayErtaş Mac Yaffey: https://github.com/danielkutik/yaffey. Builds a Yaffey.app, works perfectly on my Yosemite.

Comment: Good approach, wasn't working quite right for me. In the end I got the standard 4.0.4 x86 with working gapps by inserting all of the app, lib, and etc/permission files into the system image.

Answer (score 4):

1. Download the gapps package from http://goo.im/gapps
2. extract GoogleLoginService.apk,GoogleServicesFramework.apk and Vending.apk 
   Go to cmd window type
   `adb shell`

   3. on the shell type `mount -o rw,remount -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system`
   4. then press Ctrl+c to exit.
      cd to the directory where apks has been extracted,
   5. type `adb push <appname>.apk /system/app`
   6. then type `adb reboot`

Comment: Where I need to place the .apk file.In my project or adt bundle platform tools?

Comment: copy it to platform-tools unless you have set your PATH environmental variable

Comment: Permission Denied.

Comment: @SanyamJain Did you solve that problem? I get the same message, mount: Permission denied

Comment: @JoshuaSon: No I couldn't. And after reading from various sources I came to conclusion that It might not be worth the effort, as the emulator keeps on crashing or this strategy doesn't work for Upcoming versions of Android.
Correct me if I am wrong :)

Answer (score 3):

It is simple for me i downloaded the apk file in my computer and drag that file to emulator it install the **google play** for me
Hope it help some one

Answer (score 2):

You could download it from a Android 4.0 phone and then mount the system image `rw` and copy it over.

Didnt tried it before but it should work.

Comment: Nope, the zip with GAPPS is too big.

Answer (score 0):

---

Playstore + Google Play Services In Linux(Ubuntu 14.04)

---

Download Google apps (GoogleLoginService.apk , GoogleServicesFramework.apk )

from here http://www.securitylearn.net/2013/08/31/google-play-store-on-android-emulator/

and Download ( Phonesky.apk)
from here https://basketbuild.com/filedl/devs?dev=dankoman&dl=dankoman/Phonesky.apk

GO TO ANDROID SDK LOCATION>>

cd  -Android SDK's tools Location-

TO RUN EMULATOR>>

Android/Sdk/tools$ ./emulator64-x86 -avd Kitkat -partition-size 566 -no-audio -no-boot-anim

SET PERMISSIONS>>

cd Android/Sdk/platform-tools
platform-tools$ adb shell mount -o remount,rw -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock0 /system

platform-tools$ adb shell chmod 777 /system/app

platform-tools$ adb push /home/nazmul/Downloads/GoogleLoginService.apk /system/app/.

PUSH PLAY APKS >>

platform-tools$ adb push /home/nazmul/Downloads/GoogleServicesFramework.apk /system/app/.
platform-tools$ adb push /home/nazmul/Downloads/Phonesky.apk /system/app/.
platform-tools$ adb shell rm /system/app/SdkSetup*

Comment: System doesn't have enough space to install GAPPS.

Answer (score -1):

Have you ever tried Genymotion? I've read about it last week and it is great. They have several Android Images that you run (with their own software). The images are INCREDIBLY fast and they have Google Play installed on them. Check it out if it is the kind of thing that you need.

http://www.genymotion.com/

Comment: genymotion does not provide VMs with API level lower than 16

Comment: As a comment about Genymotion, in advise to the arbitrary reader: Genymotion uses the VirtualBox Virtualization platform. VIrtualBox is designed as to emulate Intel microcontroller platforms. Due to this limitation, It may not be possible to emulate ARM microcontroller platforms with Genymotion. 

This, of course, may serve to introduce an orthogonal question, as whether, when, and why it may be necessary to beta-test an app using a cross-platform SDK, on every single possible microconotroller or microcontroller emulator. The Intel-virt limitation may not be as much a concern, not in all apps?