# How to run the new Chrome for Android 4 on Android Emulator?

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-emulator, google-play, chrome-for-android

I want to be able to test the web based app that I am developing in the new Chrome for Android. I did install the Chrome Beta apk but every time I tried to type a URL in the address bar, the browser crashed saying "Unfortunately Chrome has stopped running".

I don't own a SmartPhone, but I need to test because my client will be using devices running Android 4+

I am running Android Emulator on OSX Lion 10.7.4. My Emulator specs:

```
Model #: sdk
Android version: 4.1.1
Kernel version: 2.6.29-gc497e41
Build #: sdk-eng 4.1.1 JRO03E 403059 test-keys
```

Apparently, the only way to get the new Chrome is through the Google Play App, which isn't a default app that comes with the emulator, so I installed and ran the Google Play App by following the instructions from this post here: [Google Play on Android 4.0 emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11154222/google-play-in-android-4-0-emulator)

I had to do a search for Chrome from within the Play Store App. Once found, it said incompatible with my device and had no button to download it.

Info about the [Chrome Browser for Android from the Play site](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.chrome&hl=en):

```
CURRENT VERSION:
18.0.1025308
REQUIRES ANDROID:
4.0 and up
```

Is there anyway to get the latest Chrome running on my emulator? When will Android Emulator developers be able to test and develop in the newly released Chrome for Android?

Answer (score 1):

Response from **deejoy** at http://blog.apkudo.com/2012/08/08/run-google-play-on-an-emulator-and-pretend-to-be-any-device/

...I did manage to get the latest chrome downloaded and installed on my emulator. However, when I run Chrome on the emulator I'm met with the following error:

```
[ERROR:context_group.cc(83)] ContextGroup::Initialize failed 
because too few vertex attributes supported.
```

So, what does that mean? Long story short, my emulator (even with OpenGL acceleration) does not support the required number of vertex attributes to run Chrome. You can take a look at Chrome's source code here: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/source/search?q=context_group.cc&origq=context_group.cc&btnG=Search+Trunk

Somewhere in context_group.cc (not necessarily line 83) you'll see an explicit check for the number of available vertex attributes and the offending error message. As far as I know, theres not much you can do (if anything) to get past this error.