# Proper Android App installation from inside an emulator

Tags: java, android, sdk, android-emulator

I recently downloaded the Android SDK (Linux, 64-bit version), and created a new AVD. I then launched the emulator from the command line, and watched my device spring to life. I then created a Gmail account, and tried to install a random (WebMD) free app from inside my emulator:

[image]

This popup is preventing me from being able to install the app. I don't see the "white shopping bag" icon that it is talking about. Any ideas as to what I have to do to get the app to properly install?

Comment: The Google Play website works only with real devices that need to be linked with the Google Play store application.

Comment: Thanks @WarrenFaith (+1) - so there's no way to install real apps on emulated Android devices? If not, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the popup indicates that you should use the Play Store app, rather than attempting to download from a browser.  The Play Store app launch icon is a shopping with a bluish-green arrow.

Comment: Thanks @grant (+1) - but this is the source of my confusion...I can't even find the Play Store app icon. Where would it be? Also, can you please read WarrenFaith's comment underneath my original question? Could my problem be stemming from what he is suggesting? Thanks again!

Comment: @IAmYourFaja, it appears the Play Store isn't available on emulators, http://stackoverflow.com/a/11155703/190648.  One option may be to get the apk you're interested in installing from other sources and push it to your emulator with adb. Or you could try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/11213598/190648