# Android Emulator don't show Play Store

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm starting on emulator64-am, SDK's official emulator, and the Play Store is missing.

Does anyone knows if the Play Store was suposed to work in this emulator?

BTW, it's pretty slow on my mac book air with 4Mb memory.

Cheers
Gustavo

Comment: Check this link.....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11154222/google-play-on-android-4-0-emulator

Comment: Answered many times already on SO, and also the slowness is another issue (also answered many times).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Slow Android emulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/slow-android-emulator)

Answer (score 3):

FYI, officially SDK's emulator don't contain Play Store app, but you can install it manually, there are many threads on web regarding how you can install it inside emulator.

Check: [Google Play on Android 4.0 emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11154222/google-play-on-android-4-0-emulator)

If you really want to have Google play installed in emulator then try [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/) emulator.