# Is there any how can we install the app on android emulator from google-play

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, google-play

Anybody tell me how to install apps on emulator from google-play store

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple Answer:

Just install first Google Play store in your emulator from ADB. and then using your gmail account you can install apps as like in your Android Phone.

OtherWise as @Williams said get apk source from anywhere and install using adb..

Link for setup Google Play service in your emulator

Check [Set Up Google Play Services](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html)

now Android 4.2.2 platform includes Google Play services. Just use an emulator running Jelly Bean. then no need to victim of using third party distributing play service apk.

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

i don't believe its possible to get APKs via google play store on the emulator; hacking concerns...  The google play app is only available to certain licensed manufacturers.  See similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11154222/google-play-on-android-4-0-emulator)

Answer (score 0):

Simple Answer : Not possible to install the app from the Google Play in emulator because Emulator does not have Play Store app.

If you can get the APK from some source then you can  install that in the simulator using the adb

Answer (score 0):

you have to download 1.ARM-Translation_v1.1.zip and 2.gapps-jb-20121212.signed.zip.
1st you have to drag the ARM-Translation and a/c to instruction you will go.
2nd step you have to drag the gapps-jb-20121212 then a/c to instruction you will go then u see in your Genymotion emulator has playstore or some google apps ....
i think i will help to you....