# run google play store on android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-play

I installed Google play store on my android emulator successfully. But when I try to run Google app it gives "Unfortunately, Google services framework has stopped" error message. I tried to fix it using clear cache of Google play store app, clear data of Google services framework app and restart the device. Also I tried for new emulators. But It didn't work. Does it a matter version of android sdk and Google Services Framework.apk version?

Suggest a way to fix this problem.

Comment: Read through the answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11154222

Comment: I installed Google play store using the steps in this post. Although it installed correctly, it gives above error messages when attempt to run Google app store.

Answer (score 2):

Read up on the guide provided by Android [here](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html).

Specifically, note:

> To test your app when using the Google Play services SDK, you must use
>   either:
>
> A compatible Android device that runs Android 2.3 or higher and
>   includes Google Play Store.
>
> The Android emulator with an AVD that runs
>   the Google APIs platform based on Android 4.2.2 or higher.

As long as you satisfy those requirements, follow the installation instructions provided to [install the SDK](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#Install) into your Developer environment.

Comment: I just wanted to install Google app store on android emulator for install an android application via Google app store,not to develop.I changed the target platform of emulator into Google APIs. Now, I can't install Google app Store on emulator.