# How to install app in playstore without Google playstore in android emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I had installed AndroVM to use Android apps in computer. But when it comes to games like shadow fight even with OpenGL support enabled, AndroVM couldn't run many games such as Hill Climb racing, Gunship battle etc. Hence I tried Genymotion. When I installed Genymotion, it automatically detected AndroVM installed in Virtual Box. And I could only run Hill climb racing and rest of them didn't work. So I finally installed Android SDK and followed all instructions to add packages(Tools, extras and System Images). Even if I have installed Google play services and Google repository, I couldn't find Google playstore in the android emulator. Even [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11154222/google-play-on-android-4-0-emulator) post suggests how to install Google playstore in emulator,it also have discussions about piracy and legal issues(in comments) and the apk's (GoogleLoginService.apk , GoogleServicesFramework.apk , Phonesky.apk) are not official packages. Hence

1. Can any one suggest how can I install apps inside emulator without using Google playstore, and
2. Why can't I find playstore even after I install Google play services and repository.

[These](http://i1374.photobucket.com/albums/ag412/padmahas/AndroidSDK_zpse23faba0.png) are the packages I've installed (Sorry I don't have enough reputation to upload image). And I'm using Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: This isn't really a programming per se, is it? wouldn't the android-enthousiasts site have more knowledge about it? http://android.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

you can't directly install apps using what google provided to you to install playstore app in emulator.
there are some 'hack' (not really) for this, but even you follow the steps, you can't install paid app in emulator also, 
I believe it is kind of difficulty made by google to prevent people to use pc to run android apps easily.
below is a detail steps how to install apps in emulator

http://blog.apkudo.com/2012/08/08/run-google-play-on-an-emulator-and-pretend-to-be-any-device/

another more up-to-date steps.

http://www.flinkd.org/2013/12/installing-google-play-on-the-android-emulator-api-18/

before all these, you should download the same version as your emulator of package from

http(s)://goo.im/gapps/

happy 'hacking'.

Comment: Hello @jp_eagle, So many have suggested this website https://goo.im/gapps/. But what I don't understand when I visit that site is, what package will install what software to my emulator. Neither names given can be understand by me nor I found any description of the package. Link of both blog and FAQ doesn't work. Do you know anything about that site?

Comment: the package in the site is stock package of google apps, for your purpose, you only require to extract out GoogleLoginService.apk, GoogleServicesFramework.apk and Phonesky.apk from one of package which is same as your avd version. you can choose latest kk(kitkat), jb(jeallybean), ics(icecreaemsanwitch) and etc.

Answer (score -1):

i have found the best emulator to be is bluestacks. It runs flawlessly in my less powered old laptop which has 2GB RAM. It is core2duo engine and has 10 years old graphics card. It does make lot of noice when i run bluestacks and gets heated. Bluestacks is the best emulator. All apps run easily in bluestacks. I have tried all emulators. None of them works in my machine except bluestacks. Youwave which is light weight app but asks for money.

Comment: Your answer isn't really relevant to the question at hand, which was about *how* to install an app. It also sounds kind of spammy.