# Easiest way to install Google Play (∼Android Store ∼Android Market) in the official Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, google-play

[In this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22376351/1198404) I have read we can do the following to "install" Google Play Services in the emulator:

Right click to a created project -> *Open Module Settings* -> *Dependencies* ->  `+` button -> *com.google.android.gms:play-services*

Then, if we can click on *Run*, our app and the **Google Play Services** should be included in the executed emulator. Unfortunately, As @gdw2 commented [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16973600/1198404): "setting up the Google Play Services SDK does not install a working Google Play app -- it just enables certain services provided by the SDK"

So, it seems the **Android "Market" is not included**. How to install it too?

[image: screenshot adding dependency]

Comment: I guess the vote down is because I did a silly question? :/

Answer (score 0):

It is not an answer for the question actually, but it is what I did:

I downloaded the apk I actually wanted to install using Google Play from my computer using: [APK Downloader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/apk-downloader/cgihflhdpokeobcfimliamffejfnmfii?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog)

I installed the apk I actually wanted using:

```
adb push myactuallywantedappnotgoogleplayapp.apk /system/app/.
```

Hopefully it will be useful to somebody.