# how to install google play store in android sdk emulator

Tags: android, shell, cmd, android-emulator, adb

I am using android SD k emulator in windows 8.1 computer and this works fine.

only problem is i unable to install Google play store in it.

i follow the link below, but no error and the problem is still same.

[Google Play on Android 4.0 emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11154222/google-play-on-android-4-0-emulator)

anybody please help me

Comment: Why would you need it? SDK emulator is for development purpose only

Comment: it means i can't install google play store in it ? 

i am installing so that i can able to test several apps before installing in my android mobile.

Comment: It is against the terms and conditions of the Google Services Framework to do this.

Comment: thanks guys, but i have seen several sites that people adding play store to their emulator thats the reason i ask.

anyways is there any geniue way to test any custom rom or apps ?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution here to to try through [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/).

You can install ARM support then Gapps by following this [guide](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2528952)