# Adding Playstore to Android Studio Emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, google-play-services

I am using Android Studios AVD to make some text virtual devices but I am unable to add the google playstore. I don't have a project as I want to download the app via the playstore. How can I get the Playstore installed on the different emulators? I've tried downloading and dropping the file onto the emulator but it just says copying file and then disappears. Any help would be great.

Comment: Take a look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11154222/google-play-on-android-4-0-emulator.

Comment: @evgenii did you ever tried that? I never got that linked methods working.

Comment: I've installed GP services on Genymotion emulator for Android 5.0 - it works perfectly.

Comment: Yeah but I like being to create a customer phone which I'm unable to do with Genymotion

Comment: @evgenii the question is about the default emulator so this is out of scope

Answer (score 2):

You cannot install the PlayStore on the emulator. There are some hacks which allow that, but I never got it managed.

Instead download that apps you need on your real phone and copy them from the device. There are multiple ways as using the backup app option of the ES Explorer app.

When you have the apks on your desktop you just need to drag and drop that apks in the new Emulator (2.0)