# Android Virtual Machine: Double Error: "Google Play Games not installed"

Tags: android, android-studio, google-api, google-play-games

I'm creating a game right now and try to implement Google Play Games SignIn.
My Problem is that (i think so) Google Play Games isn't installed right on the VM. If i start the App it'll give me the response that "Google Play Games isn't installed" (see pics). If you click on the Install or Cancel Button it'll open the same screen a second time. I don't know why. No error is displayed.

[Link to the Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BRjl.png)

Here's the whole code connected to the LogIn System:

```
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Connection Failed");

    if (mResolvingConnectionFailure) {
        // Already resolving
        return;
    }

    // If the sign in button was clicked or if auto sign-in is enabled,
    // launch the sign-in flow
    if (mSignInClicked || mAutoStartSignInFlow) {
        mAutoStartSignInFlow = false;
        mSignInClicked = false;
        mResolvingConnectionFailure = true;

        // Attempt to resolve the connection failure using BaseGameUtils.
        // The R.string.signin_other_error value should reference a generic
        // error string in your strings.xml file, such as "There was
        // an issue with sign in, please try again later."
    if (!BaseGameUtils.resolveConnectionFailure(this,
                mGoogleApiClient, connectionResult,
                RC_SIGN_IN, getResources().getString(R.string.signin_other_error))) {
            mResolvingConnectionFailure = false;
        }
    }

    // Put code here to display the sign-in button
}

public void onGoogleClick(View view){
    mSignInClicked = true;
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    // show sign-out button, hide the sign-in button
    findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    Log.d(TAG, "Connected");
    Games.Achievements.unlock(mGoogleApiClient, getResources().getString(R.string.ach_lvl3));

    // (your code here: update UI, enable functionality that depends on sign in, etc)
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Connection Suspended");
}
```

And the GoogleApiClient Declaration

```
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
            .build();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the attached image, the Google Play Service App might be outdated. You just need to update the app.

Go to Google Play and download [Google Play services](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms&hl=en). Hope that helps.

Comment: The only problem is that there isnt a way of downloading an apk on an avm

Comment: Check this [SO thread for that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11154222/google-play-on-android-4-0-emulator) about installing Google Play to emulators.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Google Page on the topic](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project)

The short version:

- Make certain Google APIs are updated in the AVD Manager
- Choose "Google APIs x86 version NN" (NN being your target) for the AVD.

Fixed Maps for me a while back - with some other minor fiddling. The problem is that not every image has Play store and/or the particular Goog API installed, so they fail. Using the Google APIs ones makes certain both are present.

HTH

Comment: I can just find Android Versions with the Google Play Apis includeded. Looks like their not updated but in my SDK Manager everything seems ok

Answer (score 0):

Okay then, couple other ideas.

1. In the "Android SDK Manager" reinstall the Google APIs (listed under extras). I don't expect that to resolve your problem, just covering bases.
2. I have never tried it, but a lot of knowledgeable people recommend Genymotion as an alternative for debugging - though lately it sounds like Play services were removed from their AVDs, this [says](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Genymotion-2.0-Emulators-with-Google-Play-support#setup-google-play-services) they're still supporting play.

Hope you get it going soon.